# Close file using with operator in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a question regarding file closing in python `with` operator

```
   import os

    with os.popen('ls') as f:
        print f.read()
        raise IOError
        print f
    print f
```

As you can see in the above piece of code I am opening a file using `with` operator, I know that the file will close automatically after exiting from the `with` block, but if some error happen inside with block what will happen to the file object `f`, will it close ?

Comment: Yes, `context managers` that `with` operates on are designed to clean up the relevant resources even in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. From the python docs:

> A context manager is an object that defines the runtime context to be established when executing a with statement. The context manager handles the entry into, and the exit from, the desired runtime context for the execution of the block of code. Context managers are normally invoked using the with statement (described in section The with statement), but can also be used by directly invoking their methods.

Commonly, context managers will implement the `try..except..finally` pattern for convenience and reusability. 
So, the answer to your question is yes it handles the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an exception will invoke the context manager's usual cleanup code.  From [PEP 343](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html), when describing context managers and the `with` statement:

> After execution of the *with-block* is finished, the object's `__exit__()` method is called, even if the block raised an exception, and can therefore run clean-up code.

Unrelated: you should be using `subprocess.Popen` (or `subprocess.call` or one of its variants) instead of `os.popen` (which has been deprecated since Python 2.6).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will close, you can test it yourself, in an interactive shell:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    a = f.read()
    print(f.closed) # Will print False
    raise IOError

print(f.closed) # Will print True
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the file will close automatically after exiting from the with block

An error will cause the `with` block to exit.